# Scala ClassNotFoundException Random Constant

Tags: scala

I have quite a few mixed scala and java projects.  They will run just fine up to some seemingly random time when they don't.

Compile goes fine, with zero errors or warnings, yet on run I get the infamous

```
ClassNotFoundException
```

In this current project I have only Scala files, and I deleted all of them and left it at a simple Test object with main method.

YET IT STILL SAYS `ClassNotFoundException`

I have scoured the net, and tried everything I have found.

Has anyone had this experience, and moreover, are there any suggestions?

Comment: Did you run a clean? For the most part this is going to get closed as too vague though....

Comment: Actually I am just noticing nothing is getting compiled to the out folder.  It was before...

Comment: Are all your package declarations at the top of each class/object correct?

Comment: @JesusAdoboLuzon They sure are.

Comment: Try closing your IDE and any build systems; in my experience problems like this are often called by an IDE deciding to rebuild the project (and therefore deleting the current class files) while it's running.

Comment: @Imm I tried restarting/cache clearing many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My other related question actually provides more insight and provides a solution to this problem.

[Running Objects in Play 2.0 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176022/running-objects-in-play-2-0-framework)

Hope it helps when everyone is using Scala in a few years...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run a run configuration for a class that have been deleted? If you're using Intellij and pressing Shift-F10 it will happily try to run a configuration even though the class does not exist anymore.

Comment: No, and I double checked to be sure.