# Running Objects in Play 2.0 Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I create a Scala Play 2.0 project then add a `Test` object with a barebones `main` function.

When I run the `Test` object I get a `ClassDefNotFoundError`.  This is because the `Test` object is apparently not being compiled into a file in any project folder.

Running the bundled Play server works fine.

Has anyone tried adding a runnable object to a Scala Play framework project and had success?

The `Test` object is being created in a new module, within the Play project named `test-module`.

**** Update ****

It seems like SBT is somehow conflicting with the 'test-module' module.  Play is an SBT project so it compiles to its 'target' directory.  However 'test-module' is not SBT and therefore wants to compile to the 'out' directory.  Problem is the compiled files never make it to the 'out' directory, in fact they don't make it to any directory at all.

Comment: Can you show your code and provide the location in the project where you created the Test object?

Comment: There is really no code to show, the Play 2.0 is is generated by IntelliJ 14.  And the Test object is a drop-in hello world.  No errors in any code, guaranteed.  Updating OP with location now.

Comment: Is `test-module` the top-level directory of your Play project? Because the application code should be inside the `app` folder by default. What exactly do you mean by *runnable object* by the way, the application's entry point?

Comment: @PermaFrost `test-module` is under the top-level directory.  I mean runnable as in the object has a main method.  It is a test for some code.  I do not need the web server or play to test it.

Comment: If it's a test I would suggest using a test framework to build it, then you can use the framework's runner via the `sbt` console, one possibility would be ScalaTest (http://scalatest.org/). If you want to run a specific main class in `sbt` you could also try `sbt run-main <fullClassName>` - you just have to make sure that your object/class is on the classpath (for a Play project that would mean inside the `app` folder). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ's template for a Play project assumes Play will be the top level directory.

When creating a module inside here, one must register it with SBT as it is not done automagically.

And make sure to follow the module->src->main->scala convention for source files, or change it in the build.sbt